# Is there a guide to help choosing titles?

Tags: discussion, title

We're [creating a guide](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4385/26643) that we can post on comments on [SO - Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) (*Stack Overflow em Português*) to help users choose titles. We have a lot of bad titles and want to work on it.

I asked there and we had no guide to use as a base, so we're starting one from scratch, but it would help if one is available in English. Can anyone point to one?

Comment: Not that I know of, but the Title section on the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page seems like a good starting place (though that may be sufficient).  Also look at the links at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Yes, I remember having seen something... It'll help, thanks. We want a pure-title guide, but it'll definitely be a start.

Comment: [This FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) on MSE might help for a good starting point. It is focused entirely on titles.

Comment: Jon Skeet has [some good advice](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Eric Lippert's [old blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/20/how-to-not-get-a-question-answered.aspx) also has some information on questions in general with links to some articles Raymond Chen wrote about email subject lines.

Comment: se duplicate [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647)

Comment: Not directly related but I liked [Ask the duck](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139974/158100)

Comment: Write your question first, then the title.

Comment: @pnuts SUM literally means add though

Comment: @pnuts Yes, but the word you used was "sum", not "add", and there's no way to use a SUM function without adding, since that's the only thing summing does. The SUM function and the mathematical definition of "add" are direct synonyms. I was merely pointing out a poor (wrong) example.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Collating the comments on the question:

- Start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

  > If you're having trouble summarizing the problem, write the title last - sometimes writing the rest of the question first can make it easier to describe the problem.
  >
  > Examples:
  >
  > - Bad: C# Math Confusion
  > - Good: Why does using float instead of int give me different results when all of my inputs are integers?
  > - Bad: [php] session doubt
  > - Good: How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?
  > - Bad: android if else problems
  > - Good: Why does str == "value" evaluate to false when str is set to "value"?
- [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) from MSE

  > 1. Make the topic stand out.
  > 2. Keep it short.
  > 3. Lead with the most important words.
  > 4. Don't start with "How do I..."
  > 5. Don't sweat replicating a tag keyword.
  > 6. "What is a ..." is fine
- Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

  > I would recommend favouring a short, descriptive title which captures the theme of the question without actually being a question instead of really trying to crowbar it into the form of a question when it really doesn’t want to be.
- Eric Lippert's [How to not get a question answered](https://ericlippert.com/2008/02/20/how-to-not-get-a-question-answered) (Talking about the inverse.)

  > Use a [difficult](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080123-00/?p=23723) or [meaningless](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070118-00/?p=28353) subject line.
- Advice from [Will](https://web.archive.org/web/20190706220245/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will)

  > Write your question first, then the title.
- [Ask the duck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139970/what-do-you-look-for-in-a-question-title-on-stackoverflow-or-any-other-se-site/139974#139974) on MSE

  > The strongest format for a question title is a question, as in "What is the strongest format for a question title?" The second strongest is a summary statement, such as "Fooing the Bar when the Baz is corrupted". The weakest is a question that looks like a Google search, such as "C# Collections issue"
- Advice from [pnuts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts)

  > Do Not Use Title Case - in addition to DO NOT SHOUT. It invites confusion between Word and a word, Access and access etc and obscures other signals, such as PivotTable is [MS], pivot table not necessarily, "sum" as in 'add' or SUM the function?