# Meta-SEO: how to choose Google-friendly question titles?

Tags: support, questions, title, seo

Is there a best practice in choosing the title of a question so that it will be easier to find it from a search engine?

This can be useful for

- People asking their own questions
- People editing someone else questions (especially with the purpose to improve all those *"Pliz halp mee"* questions that, for some reasons, obtained an answer that could be really interesting and helpful)

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306999/is-there-a-guide-to-help-choosing-titles) provides some very good advice for titles choice in general, but there's no evidence, from a SEO-ignorant perspective like mine, that what are considered good practices from SO & co. sites perspective are the same as good for people searching solutions from Google.

(I apologize if this question is a dupe. Searching for 'SEO' I had to read tons of meta-questions about... people complaining about the closure of their SEO questions on SO, and asking what is the SE site to which SEO questions belong to)

Comment: Do you mean people *answering* their own questions?

Comment: This is answered in [ask]. A good title, as described there, is SEO friendly

Comment: @ErikA I read it, but I am looking for something even more "advanced". Robert's response about "how to" titles is a good example: something that is problematic from SO user's perspective but that will probably be good for SEO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a best practice:  **Put your actual question in the title.**

This does several things:

1. It forces you to articulate, in 150 characters or less, the actual problem you are asking about.  If you can't do this, then it's highly likely that you don't really understand your problem well enough to ask with clarity how to solve it.
2. It relieves the rest of us from the burden of finding posts in Google with titles like "How to foo the bar," only to find out that we're actually reading about "How to fix this very specific error when fooing the bar."
3. It genuinely improves search mojo.

Things to avoid:

1. Don't put your attempted Google Search in the title of your question.  This doesn't help anyone else, and merely causes `S E A R C H C E P T I O N`.
2. Avoid generic titles like "help with foo."
3. Don't put tags in your titles.  Google is already very good at sussing out the relevant tags you already put on your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know who did downvote but I appreciate your advice. Some questions: what is "searchception"? Should titles contain "how to"? Do the order of the wors used in title matter?

Comment: `S E A R C H C E P T I O N` is a word-play on the movie *Inception.*  A dream within a dream.

Comment: "How to" is problematic only in the sense that the Stack Overflow community doesn't particularly care for "How to" questions.  They prefer that users try to first solve the problem themselves, and then ask on Stack Overflow when they get stuck.

Comment: The order of the words should be the same order as when an ordinary question is asked.

Comment: Why "Don't put your attempted Google Search in the title of your question."? I'd agree if you added "unless you googled using normal phrasing". Granted a google search can be terse but lately with google ai writing straightforward normal language seems to work very well. Which is a variant of "The order of the words should be the same order as when an ordinary question is asked."

Comment: @philipxy: I'm talking about Google searches where you just put in your keywords of choice.

Comment: @RobertHarvey your answer about 'howto' is a good example of what I was looking for: SEO advice applied to SO best practices. If you could expand that command in your answer it would be great.